# Get the probability, with Pascal's triangle.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have an statement that says:

> If a marriage has 5 children,
>
> That they be more women than men??

Making the pascal triangle, and adding the variables

$m = men, w = women$

$1m^5$ $5m^4w$ $10m^3w^2$ $10m^2w^3$ $5mw^4$ $1w^5$

The probability of men is $\frac{31}{32}$ and same with women.

But how does that help me get, the probability that they are more women, than men?

The correct answer should be $\frac{1}{2}$, but i cant understand how to solve it.

Comment: Hint: If $M$ is the random variable that counts men, you need to compute $P(M \geq 3)$. Which terms in the expansion do that?

Comment: Thanks Sean Roberson, best answer here

Comment: Actually, we need $P(W \geq 3)$.

Comment: Yes, in fact I did not even see that $M$, with the greater or equal, I already followed it on my own, that's why I did not realize the mistake of him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we neglect the possibility that a child is intersex, there are two possible outcomes for the sex of each child.  Hence, there are $2^5$ possible sequences of the children's sexes in our sample space.

The favorable cases consist of those sequences in which the majority of children are female.  Thus, we need to count sequences of length $5$ in which there are at least $3$ female children.  There are $\binom{5}{k}$ sequences with exactly $k$ female children since we must select which $k$ of the $5$ positions (for first, second, third, fourth, and fifth child) are occupied by female children. Hence, the number of favorable cases is 
$$\binom{5}{3} + \binom{5}{4} + \binom{5}{5}$$
Dividing this by the $2^5$ possible sequences of the children's sexes gives the desired probability.

Comment: You use the combinatorial formula, because it's like saying:

"Let's take 3 or more women of 5 total children" ? its my thought correct?

Comment: The favorable cases are those in which three or more of the children are female.  An example of such a sequence  is MFFMF.  The term $\binom{5}{k}$ counts the number of ways in which exactly $k$ children are female because we are selecting $k$ of the five possible positions in the sequence (first, second, third, fourth, or fifth child) for a female child.

Comment: +1 even if for no reason other than considering the case of an intersex child

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation is as follows.

There is one combination of 5 men. 5 men here.

There are 5 combinations of 4 men and 1 woman. +20 men. Thats 25 men and 5 women.

If you keep going like this, you will end up with 80 men and 80 women. $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of each.

Comment: I cant understand , 1/2 is probability of each one ? , but i need the probability of women be more than men

Comment: Is the question really asking: "What is the probability that there are more women than men?". Then it is still 50/50.